# Mysql2 gem installation issue and bundle install failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mysql2

I am trying to run the bundle install. My environment is Mojave and current ruby version installed as 2.3.7, I cannot do the bundle install because of the following error in the terminal. Can anyone please let me know why this is failing.

I tried bundle update as well. Nothing worked for me.

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/efutures/Documents/vhosts/Actionrev-average-costing/.bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/ext/mysql2
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby -I /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0 -r ./siteconf20191024-23547-w2j56k.rb extconf.rb --with-ldflags\=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib\
--with-cppflags\=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
checking for rb_absint_size()... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:535:in `block in try_link0'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tmpdir.rb:89:in `mktmpdir'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:532:in `try_link0'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:556:in `try_link'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:765:in `try_func'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:1051:in `block in have_func'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:942:in `block in checking_for'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:320:in `open'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:350:in `block in postpone'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:320:in `open'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:346:in `postpone'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:941:in `checking_for'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:1050:in `have_func'
    from extconf.rb:26:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Users/efutures/Documents/vhosts/Actionrev-average-costing/.bundle/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/universal-darwin-18/2.3.0/mysql2-0.4.10/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/efutures/Documents/vhosts/Actionrev-average-costing/.bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.10 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/efutures/Documents/vhosts/Actionrev-average-costing/.bundle/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/universal-darwin-18/2.3.0/mysql2-0.4.10/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.4.10), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.4.10' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: As per `You have to install development tools first`, the problem might be that you're missing the MySQL development tools (something I've encountered before on linux). I don't know how to install them on mac, but that gives you maybe some more search options on the interwebs.

Answer (score 0):

First run following in terminal,

And provide it following,

```
locate mysql_config
```

which provided, `/usr/bin/mysql_config`

And now run,

```
sudo gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/bin/mysql_config
```

Comment: Ok with the "locate" command I am getting the following output which i cannot go further.

=========================================
WARNING: The locate database (/var/db/locate.database) does not exist.
To create the database, run the following command:

  sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist

Please be aware that the database can take some time to generate; once
the database has been created, this message will no longer appear.

Comment: Do u have any idea ?

Comment: No I do not have idea, but check if you can properly login using `mysql -u root -p`

Comment: No I can't. Let me fix that first.